# How do I format getBirthday() with an annotation @MyFormat("%td.%<tm.%<tY")

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

How do I generate a class which takes a Person instance and returns the birthday as a String instead of a Date formatted with the value of the @MyFormat annotation, without writing that subclass by hand?

The purpose is the use the generated instances for HTML page generation

```java
class Person {

    @MyFormat("%td.%<tm.%<tY")
    public Date getBirthday() { return birthday; }
}

// Usage somewhere in the code

...
List<Person> people = people.parallelStream()
    .map(p -> MyFormatInterceptor.wrap(p))
    .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));


System.out.println(people.iterator().next().getBirtday()) // 31.Mai.2015
```

I have this (see below).

It doesn't matter that the return type changes from Date to String because the call is made by reflection from evaluating the expression "person.birthday".

```java
new ByteBuddy()
   .subclass(person.getClass())
   .method(isAnnotatedWith(MyFormat.class))
   .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyFormatInterceptor.class))
   .make()
   .load(person.getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
   .getLoaded();

class MyFormatInterceptor {

    @RuntimeType 
    public static Object format(@Origin Method m, @SuperCall Callable<?> zuper) {

        MyFormat formatAnnotation = m.getAnnotation(MyFormat.class);

        return String.format(formatAnnotation.value(), zuper.call());
    }
}
```

So the new class would have the same methode name "String getBirthday()" but with String as return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understand what you try to accomplish. The following code is creating a subclass of `Person` which you do not use:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(person.getClass())
  .method(isAnnotatedWith(MyFormat.class))
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyFormatInterceptor.class))
  .make()
  .load(person.getClass().getClassLoader(),                  
        ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
  .getLoaded();
```

When you use this generated subclass at runtime, calling the `getBirthday` method causes a `ClassCastException` as the `String` value cannot be cast to a `Date`. Byte Buddy does not change the return type, even when invoking a method via reflection.